# Applet works in IDE, but not in browser

Tags: applet

I have created a simple applet and HTML document, but when I open the HTML document, the applet will not show. Java is enabled, and the code should be correct. but I just get a blank page. The applet runs fine in eclipse. I tried removing the stop and destroy methods which did nothing, not sure that it would anyway, this is my first ever applet code.

I did compile the .java file using the javac command and placed the html document and .class file in the same directory.

When using IE9 it gives me the error: Lamp (wrong name: mondrian/Lamp)

APPLET CODE

```
package mondrian;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Lamp extends Applet {
    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public void start() {
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 90, 90);
        g.fillRect(250, 0, 40, 190);
        g.fillRect(80, 110, 100, 20);
    }
    public void stop() {
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

HTML DOCUMENT

```
<html>
<body>
<APPLET CODE="Lamp.class" WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=50>
</APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, found answer. I had to move my source file into the default package instead of my own -.- I do want it in mine though, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: You should post the answer as an answer rather than a comment. You should post your new question as a separate question.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, thanks :) - Nevermind, I'm not allowed to answer my own question for 8 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the class is in a package.
If you are running the class file place the html one directory below 
and refer to the class together with its package as in:

```
<applet code=mondrian.Lamp.class 
width=1200 height=1200>
</applet>
```

if you prefer to run from a jar place the html in the same directory and write

```
<applet code=mondrian.Lamp.class 
    archive="myarchive.jar"
    width=1200 height=1200>
</applet>
```

jar is more portable of course than the numerous class files in a directory that needs to carry the package name.